# How to extend Array with a function and not have typescript complain?

Tags: typescript

I want to add `Array.prototype.random()` but typescript complains. Please help.

I get `Property 'random' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Just so you're aware, I'm pretty sure that writing to the prototypes of built-in types is generally considered something of an antipattern these days.